# Oracle query with rownum and orderBy return wrong records

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I got an confusing result when working with rownum of Oracle10g.

1. first query

```
select * from A where name like '%test' order by name asc
```

==> return 1 record

2. second query with rownum

```
select * from (
    select * from A where name like '%test'
    order by name asc
 )
where rownum <= 2
```

==> return 2 records

If I remove 'order by' then it will return 1 record.

Any one can help me to explain this behavior?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Could you give some sample data that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Just in case this is a real problem (it's ringing a *very* vague bell), what exact version and patch level are you on; and what are your NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP settings? What is in the second row returned - is it a duplicate, or doesn't it match `%test` at  all?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you wanted this functionality:

```
select * from (
  select X.*, rownum r from (
    select * from A where name like '%test'
    order by name asc
  ) X
)
where r <= 2
```

or alternatively

```
select * from (
  select A.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) r
  from A where name like '%test'
)
where r <= 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! My original query is back to work properly again after I refreshed its statistic. I knew its statistic will impact the way it calculate the execute/explain plan but never heard it effects this way.